# flutter streambuilder did not update after event update

Tags: flutter, websocket, stream-builder

I have a parent page A. I pass the channel to child page B when I press the button.
here is code

```
onTap: () {
        final _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
            Uri.parse("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws/chat/$username"),
            headers:

                {"Authorization": "Token $token"});
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ChatView(
           
            channel: _channel,
          ),
        ));
```

The stream builder on page B only works the first time when I tap but after sending a message eg `channel.sink.add(command)` it did not receive any data , it only returns null.

here is a stream builder example

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: widget.channel.stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
        var data = json.decode(snapshot.data);
        List messages = data['messages'] ?? [];

        return _messageBuilder(messages);
      }
```

I want to know how to pass the stream to the child as an async snapshot.